# moles.exe exited with error code -1004 When generating dll's for x86

Tags: moles

I'm getting an Error Code -1004 When trying to generate moles assemblys for x86.

My Moles File:

```
<Moles xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/moles/2010/" Diagnostic ="true">
  <Assembly Name="mscorlib" x86="true" />
</Moles>
```

If I remove the x86="true" all works just fine

Here is the Output from Moles in my Build:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Moles\bin\Microsoft.Moles.targets(79,5): error MSB3073: The command ""C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Moles\bin\moles.exe" @C:\Projekte\Neue-FakeProjectName\Tests\ab.fakenamespace.Framework.Tests\obj\x86\Debug\Moles\moles.args" exited with code -1004.
  Result: invalid in options (-1004 - 0xfffffc14) (TaskId:9)
```

Does anyone know how to resolve my problem?

Answer (score 0):

Change the build configuration to "Any CPU".  This generally corrects Moles target platform build issues.